# Is there a simpler way exposing Stored Procedures with WCF Data Services?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, wcf-data-services

There are numerous articles over internet that explain you how to expose a stored procedure as OData via Wcf Data Services and Entity Framework. Here is one example article: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/exposing-stored-procedure-wcf

The solution is to write something like this:

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<Course> GetCoursesOrderByTitle()
{
    return CurrentDataSource
    .GetCoursesOrderByTitle()
    .AsQueryable();
}
```

Effectively you need to create a method and enumerate every single stored procedure parameter in two places: as parameters to the method above and then as parameters to the method on `CurrentDataSource`. And you need to repeat this for every single stored procedure you are exposing. This above is nothing but plumbing code. Any time a parameter changes or a type on a parameter changes you need to remember to go here and update, as if updating it in the EF model is not enough hassle.

I know that I can try and write code gen but I don't know a simple way of doing this and inserting it in the build cycle.

Does anybody have a working solution to this problem? In my project I have quite a big number of stored procedures exposed to the api and not a single but several WCF Data services that expose them and the number of these keeps growing as the API evolves. How to keep maintenance time for these low?

Comment: Yeah, we have had the same problem, and couldnt find a way out of it, and really if you are using stored procedures, the ODATA will not be much of a help, since you cannot expose your stored procs directly to the end point.